# Problem with NSMutableAttributedString with link attribute

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I run this code in Swift 5, iOS 12.1:

```
let linkText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "this is link", attributes: [.link: NSString(string: "http://example.com")])
textView.attributedText = linkText
textView.linkTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue, .underlineColor: UIColor.blue, .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single]
```

I get error:

```
[__SwiftValue integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002ba3b10
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue`

instead of `NSUnderlineStyle.single`

```
textView?.linkTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue, .underlineColor: UIColor.blue, .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
```